# Java control panel glitching or becomes yellowish

Tags: java, windows, oracle, java-8

After opening Configure Java on my PC, the Java Control Panel application loses its color and becomes yellow or dark, or the contrast becomes high. I have JDK 22 installed and JRE 8 installed. This issue affects my Logisim (logisim also becomes yellowish/random color) since it needs a minimum JRE of 1.5 to run.

[Problem Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LtTh.png)

[Problem Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRwBg.png)

[Problem Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkmve.png)

[Video of the issue for better understanding.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o8xtG5Z-g5xkf3h-9uHMcQ8ds99LiP7F/view?usp=sharing).

There is literally no solution on the internet. The closest I got is this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/1be4e6t/weird_visual_glitch_with_java_based_applications/).

I almost tried all JRE versions. This problem is weird coz it works completely fine on my laptop.

Comment: This does not seem to be [on-topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The Control Panel (and hence, support for it) [has been removed with Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/migrate/removed-tools-and-components.html#GUID-460800EF-A523-4B10-B694-E3536AC419C1). It may be hanging around in your system if you still have Java 8 installed, but don’t expect it to manage a JDK 22 version correctly and more importantly, prepare yourself for managing installed Java versions without it. Trying to figure out what’s wrong with its graphics will be a waste of time.